# Unable to generate Certificate and Profile

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iosdeployment

In iTunes connect when I try to add the application I got the following prompt

[image]

I clicked on [Register one here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleCreate.action)

and I was redirected to free account page

[image]

But I was requested to join my clients team and I have done all things stated in mail. I checked my role in iTC and its this [image]

Now I wish adding application and generating certificate and profiles. How will I do it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select a proper team. Click on your name in top right corner on developer.apple.com Account's page, there should be a popup with your team's name.

Comment: this does not show the team name, I see only signout button there

Comment: @iDev Apple developer program and iTunes connect are not the same. You need separate invite to developer team.

Comment: "Team members aren't the same as iTunes Connect users" it's from Apple's documentation

Comment: can I have the link from which my client can invite me ?

Comment: @iDev I can't copy the link, but it's a big blue button on the People screen. http://imgur.com/Ffhx2zP